# Badge showing in available after completing quest

Tags: support, bug

[image]

In the above screenshot you can see I've already crossed the quest. But it is still not awarding it to me and remaining in the available list.

Can anyone say what is the reason of this and what to solve this issue.

## **Update 1:**

As of seeing answer of the duplicate linked question what I understand is I've to maintain a positive question record, not only good question.

The [Curious badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious) has two criteria to be awarded:

1. Ask a good question on 5 separate days
2. Maintain a positive question record

> **My Suggestion** is to make them separate or split that count with negative mark beside it. As it is looking odd on seeing 6/5 completed
>   and still pending. Just asking to make it more user friendly look.

Comment: If you choose to track the badge and click/hover on the progress tracker itself, you'll see that there is some indication (a red cross) that indicates you're lacking a positive question record.

Comment: That indicates but not the count is lack. Just saying it's confusing in this look.